# SPI Seems garbled on MSP430

Tags: spi, msp430

I'm trying to get sensible bits out of a Bus Pirate hooked up to a Launchpad board (Using the Sparkfun cable: Orange goes to P1.6, Yellow to P1.5. This should be correct, unless I have MOSI and MISO confused...). I don't have CS hooked up, since I'm just using the bus pirate to monitor anything.

The bus pirate is set up for SPI, 125KHz, Clock polarity Idle low, output clock edge Active to idle, input sample phase middle, /CS, output is normal.

On the Launchpad, I have a MSP430G2231 with no external crystal. Using Code Composer Studio, I have the following:

```
#include  "msp430g2231.h"
volatile unsigned char value=0;

#pragma vector=USI_VECTOR
__interrupt void universal_serial_interface(void)
{
    value+=1;
    USISRL=value;
    USICNT=8;
}
void main(void){
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;

    BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;                    // Set range
    DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;
    BCSCTL2 &= ~(DIVS_3);

    USICTL0 |= USIPE7 +  USIPE6 + USIPE5 + USIMST + USIOE;
    USICTL1 |= USIIE;
    USICKCTL = USIDIV_3 + USISSEL_2;
    USICTL0 &= ~USISWRST;
    USISRL=value;
    USICNT = 8;

    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits+ GIE);  
}
```

Most of this is cobbled together from the various samples. After much reading of the data sheet, it does seem that the USI clock is set to run at 125KHz (SMCLK of 1MHz, divided by 8), although I do not have a scope to measure this.

When running, I get what is essentially garbage out of the bus pirate. P put a breakpoint on the first line of the USI interrupt vector, and had it go through three times, so I should have gotten 0, 1, 2 from the bus pirate

```
0x00(0x00)0x00(0x00)][0x40(0x00)]
```

And letting it free run, I just get stuff like this:

```
[0xFF(0x00)][0x3F(0x00)][0x7F(0x00)][0xBF(0x00)][0xC0(0x00)0x00(0x00)][0x40(0x00)0x80(0x00)]
```

Which still looks nothing like what I'm expecting.

I've spent most of the evening going through the users guide for the chip, and I'm still stumped.

While writing this, I discovered that I can use the Bus Pirate as a logic analyzer (using LogicSniffer), and set it up to do so. And modified the program to write 0x55 to `USISRL`, and change the `USIDIV` to `USIDIV_4` to slow things down a bit more, and here's the results:
[image]

The clock signal looks good, LogicSniffer reports that it's about 285KHz... and MOSI is... special. I would expect a nice alternating pattern, since I'm writing out 0x55, and that's anything but.

Any one have any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? Defective chip? Something else?

EDIT:
Ok, minor amount of idiocy on my part. I didn't change the value that gets written to SPI in the interrupt. Doing this results in the expected pattern:

[image]

However, going back to attempting to write out an incrementing byte gets me garbage:
[image]

So, I still have a problem, just not as big of a one as I thought...

EDIT 2:
Thanks to the comments below, I tied the ground wire off the Bus Pirate cable, which was previously unconnected, to the ground off my power supply (Sparkfun's breadboard power supply). Previously, the closest ground they shared was back in the USB hub I'm hanging all this equipment off of.

This removed the glitching on MOSI when running the counter program, and LogicSniffer can now decode the bytes correctly on its own:
[image]

The bus pirate in monitor mode still reports odd results:

```
[0x00(0x00)][0x04(0x00)][0x06(0x00)][0x10(0x00)][0x10(0x00)][0x10(0x00)][0x12(0x00)][0x18(0x00)]
```

It does seem better able to detect the ends of the writes (I'm assuming that's what the square brackets delimit), but the data is decodes is still off. I'm not quite as concerned now that the waveform looks better, but it would still be nice to know why the Bus Pirate is getting confused.

Comment: That last diagram looks like it has glitches on the MOSI line, could be crosstalk from the clk.  Do you an oscilloscope?  What's you wiring like - do you have good solid short ground between the BusPirate and the MSP430?

Comment: I agree with @MartinThompson. The MOSI line is glitching and the Bus Pirate is getting confused. If you squint a little at the second picture and ignore what Bus Pirate thinks it sees (I just typed the binary I see into Windows calculator and converted to hex) you get 6B-6C-6D, incrementing like you want. You need to clean up the wiring between the Bus Pirate and the MSP.

Comment: I don't see a `while(1);` or equivalent at the end of main() to stop it exiting and doing random stuff.

Comment: @OliGlaser, if I'm reading the sheet right, going into LPM0 actually halts CPU execution until an interrupt occurs. Most, if not all of TI's samples use this. It makes sense, since they tout the MSP430s as low power parts, and a busy loop isn't very power friendly.

Comment: @MattSieker - Ah okay, I don't use MSP430s so I didn't recognise that instruction. Don't you have to send it back to sleep after the interrupt though? or does it do that automatically?

Comment: @OliGlaser, the power mode is stored in the `SR` register, and the data sheet says to push `SR` on the stack at the start of the handler, and pop it back off when it's done, restoring the power mode. I'm assuming that the compiler with CCC does that, though I'd have to look at what exactly it emits. So, in short, it does appear to be automatic-ish.

Comment: Oh, seems I was mistaken, pushing and popping SR is done by the chip. So, it is automatic.

Comment: Another error might be to get the SPI modes wrong. You didn't show how you set up the BP. When the data gets read by the BP the same moment the MSP writes to it, you get strange results.

Comment: You are having the Bus pirate sample at the same frequency as the SPI clock. You will be missing samples and will have issues with the data. What you think you might be seeing might be wrong. It is a must to have your sampling rate at least twice as high as the SPI clock rate, and actually x10 is even better. Until this isn't met, don't trust anything you see on the logic diagram.

Comment: This won't fix your problem, buy you DO need to connect and use /CS, otherwise any bit skip will mess up all of your following byte boundaries.  By the way, how is that output [0x00(0x00)][... interpreted anyway?  Meaning what is the difference between the numbers inside/outside the parentheses?

Comment: Oh my, I just noticed this is > 1 year old.

Answer (score 3):

MSP430 is a MCU example tha invert the CPHA naming convention, thus diverging from  the standard SPI description: TI MSP430 uses the name UCCKPL instead of CPOL, and its 
UCCKPH is the **inverse** of CPHA. When connecting two chips together, carefully examine the clock phase initialization values to be sure of using the right settings.

Answer (score 1):

[image: MSP430 USCI SPI timing diagram]

<sub>(Image source: [Texas Instruments MSP430x5xx and MSP430x6xx Family User's Guide, SLAU208, Chapter 37](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau208q/slau208q.pdf))</sub>

As @Dirceu has said, the normal convention states that the receive operations must be handled in the **leading** edge of the pulse, if CPHA = 0. However, MSP430 somehow define CKPH instead of CPHA in such a way that CKPH is inverse of CPHA.